# Forms Authentication in an ASP.NET app not being passed to new MVC app. Can it be done?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I work with 100's of ASP.NET (vb.net) web applications at a hospital which all use Forms Authentication.  We are trying to move to MVC and within an MVC app if I check the "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" it always is blank.  If I check the same value in any of the other ASP.NET web apps the value contains the user information I need.  The MVC app is set to Forms Authentication (as is the IIS setting for the MVC app)  My code to retrieve the "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" follows:

```
public static string CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        string SessionLocation = string.Format("BasePage_CurrentUser{0}", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        if ((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionLocation] == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionLocation])))
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionLocation] = FHSBase.FHS.FHSSettings.AuthenticatedUser;
        }
        return Convert.ToString(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionLocation]);
    }
    set
    {
        string SessionLocation = string.Format("BasePage_CurrentUser{0}", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionLocation] = value;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?  Why would my other ASP.NET apps all see the user but the new MVC is always blank?

Comment: How to you create FormAuthentication ticket? Are you trying to achive Single Sign On? If so, are those ASP.Net Applications in same domain?

Comment: When you first connect to the site anonymously `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` will contain an empty string.  To force a redirect to the login controller, you may need to add an `Authorize` attribute to other controllers.

Comment: No we are not trying to achieve single sign-on.   In many stations the same computer is shared (users logs in with a generic sign on) then when going to the Intranet, they must sign in with their username and password.

Comment: I first go to a web app and sign on, then go to the MVC app to see if it has my information (which it does not.)  The user should already be signed in by the time they reach this app (for now.)  The apps are in the same domain.

Comment: Ticket created like so:        `code`   Dim UserData As String = String.Format("EMPID={0}&NAME={1}&SSN={2}&MNEMONIC={3}&DEPT={4}&JOBCODE={5}", EmpId, Name, SSN, "", Dept, JobCode)
            UserData = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(UserData)
            Ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, SSN, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), False, UserData)) `code`